# shortest path & max flow

Tags: graph-algorithms, linear-programming, max-flow

I am trying to improve my algorithmic knowledge during the summer break and i found this problem in a book.

We have an undirected graph $G=(V,E$) with starting node $s\in V$ and last node $t \in V$ where weight of every edge $(u,v) \in E$ is a positive number ($w(u,v)>0$).

Actually it asks to prove that finding the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ is equivalent with finding a max flow $f$ from $s$ to $t$.

$f$ minimizes the amount of $Σ_{(u,v)\in E} f(u,v)w(u,v)$ and has the value of $|f|=1$.

It seems that i am missing something. Can anyone help me with this cause i really hate leaving unsolved exercises when reading a book.

Thanks.

Comment: Which book (and which exercise) is this?

Comment: Seems to be off-topic here, voted to close.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing, where you minimize the sum of $f(u,v)w(u,v)$ with a given flow value $|f|$ isn't, in fact, the max-flow problem—it's the [min-cost flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). If you constrain the flow value to be 1, and all capacities are set to 1, it's pretty clear that this problem is equivalent to finding the shortest path.

Basically, unit-capacity flow problems find edge-disjoint paths. If you set the flow value to be 1, you'll find only a single path. If you're working with min-cost flow, that path will necessarily be the shortest path (and, therefore, the cheapest flow).

If this is *not* what the book is asking, and it's really asking you about max-flow, I suspect there must be some details missing from your description. (For example, you could easily have a single node $t'$ before $t$, with $c(t',t)=1$, so max-flow would have a flow value of 1, yielding a single path; however, that would still ignore the edge costs, and would just find any path, *unless* you're specifically using the Edmonds-Karp algorithm, which uses BFS to find its augmenting paths; in that case, you would, at least, find the shortest *unweighted* path.)

Answer (score 1):

Shortest path costs $O(E)$ using breadth-first search
The best algorithms for max-flow are something like $O(EV)$ (plus some logarithmic factors).

So I do not know in what sense they are equivalent (other than they are both polynomial time)

Comment: That's what i've thought and i decided to ask here. I am really confused of what to do.

Comment: The shortest paths he's talking about are weighted, so BFS is probably not relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Actually finding the min-cut from s to t (whose cut has the minimum capacity cut) is equivalent with finding a max flow f from s to t.

There are different ways to find the augmenting path in Ford-Fulkerson method and one of them is using of shortest path, therefore, I think the mentioned expression was something like above.

Some other ways to choose augmenting path:

1 - Fattest path : Implemented by using priority queue.

2 - DFS path : Implemented by using stack(DFS).

3 - Random path : Implemented by randomized queue.

https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part2/lecture/xmDao/running-time-analysis

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about min-cuts so I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Dear @D.W. I was just saying, maybe the mentioned expression was something about relationship between max-flow and min-cuts not max-flow and shortest path or something about choices for finding augmenting path.